# Handshake error to mysql via ssl

Tags: mysql, mongodb, ssl, amazon-ec2

**tldr:**  I get the following error with a client/server setup with ssl:

**Specifically: ssl configuration error: UseCertificateChainFile: SSL errors: PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib**

**The details:**

I am hosting something similar to a mysql server on ec2 (specifically mongosqld)

I need to connect to it via ssl, so I create certs using openssl on the machine using this set of instructions provided by mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html

I run the server with the following command

`mongosqld --schema=schema.drdl \
           --addr=0.0.0.0:3307 \
           --auth \
           --sslMode=allowSSL \
           --sslCAFile=ca.pem \
           --sslPEMKeyFile=server-key.pem`

And on my machine, I attach to the server like so:

`mysql --protocol tcp \
       --host my.host.on.amazon.com --port 3307 \
       --enable-cleartext-plugin \
       --ssl-cert mongosqlcerts/client-cert.pem 
       --ssl-key mongosqlcerts/client-key.pem 
       --ssl-ca mongosqlcerts/ca.pem`

On the client side I get the following error:
`SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)`

On the server logs, a bit more helpful:

```
mongosqld starting: version=v2.3.1 pid=11461 host=ip-xx-xx-xx-xx
I CONTROL    [initandlisten] git version: fa3535342a4c5abe36e3cc28a2ecf72864dfc6fe
I CONTROL    [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
I CONTROL    [initandlisten] options: {schema: {path: "schema.drdl"}, net: {bindIp: [0.0.0.0], ssl: {mode: "allowSSL", PEMKeyFile: "server-key.pem", CAFile: "ca.pem"}}, security: {enabled: true}}
I NETWORK    [initandlisten] waiting for connections at [::]:3307
I NETWORK    [initandlisten] waiting for connections at /tmp/mysql.sock
I NETWORK    [conn1] connection accepted from 108.20.XXX.XXX:63353 #1 (1 connection now open)
E NETWORK    [conn1] handshake error: ERROR 1043 (08S01): recv handshake response error: ERROR 1043 (08S01): ssl configuration error: UseCertificateChainFile: SSL errors: PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib
2017-12-01T22:24:50.394+0000 I NETWORK    [conn1] end connection 108.20.XXX.XXX:63353 (0 connections now open)
```

Specifically: **ssl configuration error: UseCertificateChainFile: SSL errors: PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
    SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib**

Can anyone help me parse that error.

Thanks friends!

Comment: Don't you have to use these specific parameters? e.g. --mongo-mongossl there is a full list at this page https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/v2.1/reference/mongosqld/#cmdoption-mongo-ssl

Comment: From what I understand, those are to connect the Connector to the mongo instance.  My issue is from the mysql client to the Connector

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it!

so for the `sslPEMKeyFile` argument in mongosqld as stated in the docs you need to

Specifies the .pem file containing **both** the TLS/SSL **certificate** and **key** for MySQL clients. Specify the file name of the .pem file using relative or absolute paths.

So when I used openssl to create ca, server-cert and key files, I needed to create a new file that combined the private-key and the server-cert

so I created a new file called combined.pem with the following text in it:

`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
(Your Private Key: your_domain_name.key) 
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
(Your Primary SSL certificate: your_domain_name.crt) 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

and started the server with that and it worked!!!

Comment: I followed the script provided in the above url and can't get mysql connect to mongosqld. I am getting handshake response error: ERROR 1043 (08S01): ssl configuration error: SSL errors: 140760fc:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol